# Pandas - Сложить все значения в списке ячейки

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть датафрейм такого вида:

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [1.0, 2.0] | [5.0, 2.0] | [7.0, 1.0] |
| [2.0, 2.0] | [1.0, 2.0] | [7.0, 1.0] |

Нужно сложить списки в каждой ячейке, т.е. превратить в такой:

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3.0 | 7.0 | 8.0 |
| 4.0 | 3.0 | 8.0 |

Как сделать это максимально просто?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться методом `.apply()` для каждого столбца, этот способ самый простой и понятный:

```
df['x'] = df['x'].apply(lambda x: sum(x))
df['y'] = df['y'].apply(lambda x: sum(x))
df['z'] = df['z'].apply(lambda x: sum(x))
```

Учтите, что если в столбцах будут элементы не в виде списка, то будет выдавать ошибку.
Если столбцов много и вручную делать для каждого столбца долго, то вот вариант, который просуммирует значения во всех столбцах:

```
cols = df.columns
for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: sum(x))

df
```

Comment: Да и короткая версия `.apply(sum)` должна по идее сработать. А насчёт второй части ответа, может тут `applymap` можно применить, чтобы без цикла обойтись.

Comment: Не знал, что так можно, спасибо за совет, постараюсь запомнить) @CrazyElf

Comment: Ну, в питоне много где "функциональный стиль" можно использовать, и не только в пандасе )

Comment: Ну я питон не так давно учу, всего месяца 3, поэтому еще не все фишки крутые знаю)
Ну и после курсов по пандас как то сильно привык, что в apply всегда лямбда функцию суют) @CrazyElf

Comment: Ну, такое. Обычно всё, что делают через лямбду, можно сделать без неё. Но если сразу не получается сообразить как, то полезно хоть через лямбду уметь

Answer (score 2):

просто примените `applymap`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":[[1.0, 2.0],[2.0, 2.0]], "y":[[5.0, 2.0],[1.0, 2.0]], "z":[[7.0, 1.0], [7.0, 1.0]]})
df = df.applymap(sum)
print(df)
```

```
     x    y    z
0  3.0  7.0  8.0
1  4.0  3.0  8.0
```

Comment: поздно заметил комментарий @CrazyElf. помечу ответа как общий.

Comment: Не знал про .applymap(), на стак оверфлоу узнаю больше инфы, чем на курсах)

Comment: @Step1709 это нормально. потому что здесь реальные кейсы.

Comment: поэтому я и сижу здесь в последнее время, набираюсь реального опыта и знаний, к счастью здесь много ребят, шарящих в теме лучше меня, так что есть у кого подсмотреть полезную инфу)